# white label error when i generate pdf

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, browser, spring-restcontroller

I use spring boot and I use this code to generate pdf document.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/members/{memberId}/contract/{contractId}/generalcontracts", produces = "application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getMemberContract(@PathVariable("memberId") Long memberId, @PathVariable("contractId") Long contractId) throws IOException {
    byte[] content = reportService.generateMemberContractReport(contractId);
    return prepareReport(content);
}

private ResponseEntity<byte[]> prepareReport(byte[] content) throws IOException {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    String filename = "report.pdf";
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```

In js, I do

```
<button id="memberPrintReport" type="button"  class="btn btn-primary">Imprimer</button>

$("#memberPrintReport").on('click', function (e) {
    tryit(getHostName() + "/members/" + memberId + "/contract/" + contractId + "/generalcontracts");
}    

function tryit(urlServer) {
    var win = window.open('_blank');
    downloadFile(urlServer, function (blob) {
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        win.location = url;
    });
}
```

A new tab open, I see during a few second a white label error and after I see the pdf.

I don't understand why I get during a few instant this white label error

Image of the white label error
https://imagebin.ca/v/3Wnqxfpq1yR6

edit:

```
function downloadFile(url, success) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + $.cookie('authorization'));
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (success)
                success(xhr.response);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Edit

that work with chrome, but not with firefox

```
function tryit(urlServer) {
  downloadFile(urlServer, function (blob) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     window.open(url, '_blank');

  });
}
```

Comment: What is the content of the whitelabel error?

Comment: @Kirby, updated message

Answer (score 0):

Your are executing this line: `var win = window.open('_blank');` which result in opening http://localhost:8080/_blank, as javascript understand `_blank` as url. so you need to update your `tryit` function to this:

```
function tryit(urlServer) {
    downloadFile(urlServer, function (blob) {
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(url,'_blank');
    });
}
```

Comment: don't work with firefox... that open and close. with chrome that do nothing

Comment: Can you hit PDF API directly into browser . Check whether it download or just open inside browser

Comment: i updated... working with chrome but not with firefox, i see it's a pdf in response